# React jest pass data to mounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a component that use context. After I mount it (shallow does not work with useContext apparently) I am trying to set default values for the component data.

I was expecting `const contextValues = { text: 'mock', msg: 'SUCCESS' };` and passing that to the AlertContextProvider to set a state for that component but I am probably looking at this the wrong way.

AlertContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

export const AlertContext = createContext();


const AlertContextProvider = props => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    text: '',
    msg: ''
  });

  const updateAlert = (text, msg) => {
    setAlert({
      text,
      msg
    });
  };
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={{ alert, updateAlert }}>
      {props.children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AlertContextProvider;
```

Alert.js (component):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './Alert.scss';
import { AlertContext } from '../context/AlertContext';

const Alert = () => {
  const { alert } = useContext(AlertContext);

  return (
    <div className='alert'>
      <p className="alert-para">{alert.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

Alert.js(text)

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Alert from '../components/Alert';
import AlertContextProvider from '../context/AlertContext';

describe('Alert', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const contextValues = { text: 'mock', msg: 'SUCCESS' };

    // Below mounting is  needed as Enzyme does not yet support shallow mocks
    wrapper = mount(
      <AlertContextProvider value={contextValues}>
        <Alert />
      </AlertContextProvider>
    );
  });

  test('Should render a  paragraph', () => {
    const element =wrapper.find('.alert-para');
    expect(element.length).toBe(1); // this is correct
    expect(element.text()).toEqual('mock'); // THIS FAILS AS THE VALUE OF THE ELEMENT IS AN EMPTY STRING WHILE I WAS EXPECTING 'mock'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `contextValues` through `value` prop on `<AlertContextProvider />` but you are never using that prop to initialize data inside your context provider.

In this example, I used `useEffect` hook as `componentDidMount` to initialize your state AlertContext.js`

```
const AlertContextProvider = props => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    text: '',
    msg: ''
  });

  // The same as component did mount
  useEffect(() => {
    setAlert({
      text: props.value.text,
      msg: props.value.msg
    })
  }, [])


  const updateAlert = (text, msg) => {
    setAlert({
      text,
      msg
    });
  };

  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={{ alert, updateAlert }}>
      {props.children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

You should use `useCallback` hook for your `updateAlert` function to memoize it.

Comment: above code breaks my component as props.value is undefined. The test seems to work with that code though, any idea on whats happening? When I use the component in my code I dont pass those props in

Comment: I created above example from the standpoint of your tests. Here is example in codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jl7vxk6zv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

"above code breaks my component as props.value is undefined" looks like you are using your component differently than you are testing it